# Why couldn’t the Burgess B Clock built in 1974 be built in 1775 by Harrison?

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

In the Royal Observatory in London they have a mechanical clock called the [Burgess B](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Burgess#Notable_clocks), based on a 200 year old design by [Harrison](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Harrison).

[image]

[image]

[image]

My question is: **Why couldn’t the Burgess B Clock built in 1974 be built in 1775 by Harrison?**

Comment: Harrison made his claim in his 1775 book *Concerning Such Mechanism*.  He died in 1776, so perhaps he simply did not have time to complete an example, which, presumably, would have taken many years as well as incurring considerable expense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps it could be, in principle, given desire and unlimited time and money. But it took even Burgess to build a "nearly identical" clock "nearly 11 years" (Harrison died in 1776), and he used modern materials, mostly duraluminium and invar (a nickel-iron alloy), only the mechanism design was Harrison’s. The purpose of building Clock B was specifically to test Harrison's claim that his designs could remain within 1 second over 100 days, and apparently no one believed or perhaps even understood Harrison's claims in 1775. [The Independent had Betts](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/science/john-harrisons-longitude-clock-sets-new-record-300-years-on-10187304.html), a senior horologist at the Royal Observatory, comment on the matter:

> "*In his later years, Harrison had left instructions on how to build the clock in an obscure book, which was so hard to read it became known as “the ramblings of superannuated dotage” by later horologists. “It was a claim that Harrison made and a claim nobody believed because the best clocks of the day couldn’t do better than about a second a week, if they were lucky,” Mr Betts said. “So the idea that somebody was going to keep time to an accuracy of a second in a 100 days was preposterous. It was only in the 20th century that people thought that Harrison may have been right.*
>
> [...] *“This does not claim to be a replica of Harrison’s clock. It claims to be the use of Harrison’s design and concept. It’s important to realise his design goes against everything the establishment has claimed is the best throughout history,” Mr Betts said. Traditional clockmaking argued that a heavy pendulum bob and a short swing would make for good timekeeping. However, Harrison thought the opposite and designed a clock with a relatively light pendulum bob and wide swing. “That was such a radical difference it was another reason why they didn’t believe it. They thought it was rather heretical,” Mr Betts explained.”*"

Answer (score 3):

Harrison spent most part of his later life trying to perfect the marine chronometer, and to win the Longitude prize (the prize was eventually collected by his widow). This clock is not a marine chronometer, as far as I can tell from the picture, and probably Harrison had no time and resources to build it.

The demand for a stationary high precision clock at that time was not as urgent
as for a practical marine chronometer. Making a single high grade clock or watch
at the time of Harison consumed years and a lot of money because all parts (and tools!) had to be made by hand.

Comment: " (the prize was eventually collected by his widow). " Not correct. He collected the prize during his lifetime but died not too many years later.